# How to use Date/time as Date field in Sobject Validation rule?

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I need to compare one date field (Date/Time) with Parent Objects Date field(Date/Time). When these two values are not equal then need to fire validation rule.

Formula:

```
DATEVALUE( CallDateTime__c ) <> ( $ObjectType.CallPresentation__c.Fields.OCE__OffCreatedDate__c )
```

DATEVALUE function is not working for `$ObjectType.CallPresentation__c.Fields.OCE__OffCreatedDate__c`

Now i need to compare both as Dates. Can anyone please suggest me how to convert date/time to date when we use sobject formula?

Answer (score 3):

The [`$ObjectType` global](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype.htm#!) gives you access to refer to elements of your Salesforce org's schema. It does not provide access to cross-relationship data, or any data at all in actual records; it only yields information about the objects and fields in the org.

If your object has a field `Relationship__c`, you'd refer to its fields in a validation rule via the standard `Relationship__r.Some_Field__c` notation for traversing relationships.

Comment: Ok David, But i need to write validation rule on Parent object. there is a lookup relationship. How do we write validation rule on Parent object? I think Process builder or trigger will work right?

Comment: You can't write a validation rule on a parent object that references child objects unless the parent object also has a lookup relationship to the child (i.e, you have a circular reference.